# add to stat once after unlocking

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am in the middle of making a RPG, where you can unlock feats to either perform combo attacks or increase your stats ONCE. I am trying to write a code that makes the feat for stat increase only run once after unlocking it (so the stat does not increase eternally). so far, I have written it as:

```
armed = False
arm = 0
if armed == True:
    if arm == 0:
        strength += 2
        arm += 1
```

This does not only look ugly, but I have a suspicion that this will end up running forever then armed is unlocked (armed=True). So what is an effective (and hopefully simple) way of running the loop once and only once ?

Comment: Don't use a loop? Make a function instead, your question seems too broad

Comment: There's no loop here... an `if` statement will only run once.

Comment: I think you need to expand more on the context of your code. Based on your intro statement, it seems like you should perform a check on if the feat was accomplished first before providing the bonuses that feat gives. If you have the rewards of each feat in its own function, then it can make the rest of this system a lot simpler to handle.